# Netbeansで依存しているプロジェクトのソースを確認したい。

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, uml

タイトルの通りです。
ご存知の方教えてください。

Netbeansは8.0を使っています。

**追記**
今回の目的は、Netbeansの「宣言へ移動」機能を使用した際に、ソースが読めること。
また、UMLでグラフィカルにクラス図を見ることもできるならば、その方法を教えてください。

現在、JavaEEでWebシステムを作っており、
依存性はいずれもMavenで管理しています。

```
POM.xml

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mavenで依存しているライブラリのソースを参照したいという話であれば、ソースを参照したいjarを右クリックして「ソースをダウンロード」を選択すればOKです。
なおNetBeansプロジェクト自体がmavenプロジェクトとなっていることが前提です。

[image: mavenプロジェクト例]

依存するライブラリのソースをまとめてダウンロードしたい場合は「依存性」を右クリックしてから開くメニューからでも可能です。

---

ソースのダウンロードが完了すればclassファイルのダブルクリックでソースを参照できます。もちろんユーザが開発しているソースから「宣言へ移動」でもジャンプできます。

[image: ソースの参照例]

---

なおライブラリの依存関係についてはUMLとはちょっと違いますが、「アーティファクトの詳細表示」→「グラフ」タブ→「グラフの表示」という手順で図示可能です。

[image: 依存関係の図]